# How to Write data to file in angularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, save, writetofile

I have a variable  with huge data some thing like this.

```html
$scope.employees = [
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe",
      "city": "Bangalore","State":karnataka,},

    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith",
       "city": "Hyderabad","State":AndraPradesh,},

    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName": "Jones",
      "city": "Mumbai","State":Maharastra,},
];
```

I want to save it to JSON file, when I click a button or something.

Answer (score 4):

$scope.employees is the object to be saved to a file

```
$scope.savedJSON = angular.toJson($scope.employees,true);
var blob = new Blob([$scope.savedJSON],{
   type: "application/json;charset=utf-8;"
});
var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
downloadLink.setAttribute('download', 'sampleJSON.txt');
downloadLink.setAttribute('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
downloadLink.click();
```

Answer (score -1):

[angular.toJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) should help you out.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {
$scope.employees = [
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe",
  "city": "Bangalore","State":karnataka,},

{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith",
   "city": "Hyderabad","State":AndraPradesh,},

{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName": "Jones",
  "city": "Mumbai","State":Maharastra,},
];



$scope.savedJSON = '';

$scope.save = function () {
    $scope.savedJSON = angular.toJson($filter('filter')($scope.employees, $scope.searchText));
};
}]);

var blob = new Blob([scope.save],{
type: "application/json;charset=utf-8;"
});
downloadLink.attr('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

Comment: Uhm... Why is this being downvoted? An explanation would be nice.

Comment: I guess that they didn't understand how it works, and didn't want to take the time to try it. maybe an explanation, or a Plunk?