# write data to local browser storage in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am developing the front end of an application in AngularJS. Input is given in a search box, on clicking the search button, I have to save the data in a text file. (The input will be a string). How do I do this?

Also, after this operation, I have to view the output stored in a text file in the html. How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? share some code... or are you expecting code from scratch?

Comment: I just googled very "angularjs writing to file", wasn't that hard to find out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536265/how-to-write-data-to-file-in-angularjs

Comment: What you mean by saying "save"? Do you want to write in file system or in memory?

Comment: i want to write in file system. currently for displaying the text file - i am using embed src.

Comment: @DenisBokor angular.toJson saves it in .json format..... for me the requirement is -- suppose the search box has "alpha beta gamma", on clicking search button, a new file (lets call it "pqr.txt") pqr.txt is created in the file system, and the content of the text file is "alpha beta gamma"

Comment: why the downvotes? i couldn't find the solution to this...

Comment: You cannot write to file system from javascript. It's strictly forbidden by the browsers itself.

Comment: @akashrajkn write to any file would be a serious security hole.

Comment: Why do you need to save to a text file? ... How about a "data storage" like a database? ... Do the end user need to access the text file from somewhere else?

Comment: No, the end-user does not need access to the text file. I will try using a database like you suggested, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite often the saved data is not for the end user but the app.

A text file seems often as a simple and quick way (which is kind of isn't when we talk about web apps and client side access).

At this link, [Client-Side Storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/), you find a few "local storage solution" and their pros/cons, which you can compare with server based databases, to find the best way for your app.

And as its title says, the benefit of client side storage is access to it without internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the full power of the File System API only if you can get the user to select the file you need to write to. You can use cookies in your code if that is not your case.

The `saveData` function can save whatever the string you need in a cookie. The file will be there even after you close the browser (set for 30 days in my example).

The loadData function returns the data you saved in a previous session.

Use `$cookies` provider in Angular if you use it. It sums the things up in a nicer way.

You will see that cookies can do much more things including saving multiple data sets in multiple files if you explore bit more by googling about it.

```
function saveData(searchQuery) {

    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (30*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();

    document.cookie = "mySearch=" + searchQuery + "; expires=" + expires;
```

};

```
   function loadData() {
       return document.cookie;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link : [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx). Another way is to use the [angular.toJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) method, save into a json file and access it as needed